# How long can cream cheese frosting be safely stored in the fridge?

Tags: baking, storage-lifetime, cream-cheese

I made a cream cheese frosting a while ago.  I didn't use all the frosting, so I put the rest (quite a lot actually) in the fridge with the intent to freeze it by the weekend if I hadn't used it.  Fast forward a month and it's still in the fridge.  I don't have the exact recipe in front of me, but it's cream cheese, powdered sugar, butter, extract, and milk.  The milk is minimal and I can't remember if I actually used it (I don't always).

I should note that I keep my refrigerator very cold (veggies usually freeze after a couple days - I like milk super cold).  I don't know if that would help preserve it longer, but thought it might be relevant.

Comment: No matter how close the temperature was to freezing, if it is not frozen solid all the time, it is considered fridge storage. And fridge storage for all prepared foods is 3-5 days regardless of ingredients, nowhere near a month. There are a few classes which are an exception, e.g. refrigerator pickles, but if you didn't use a recipe intended for storage, you will practically always end up with food which is not safe after the fifth day.

Comment: I did see that question/answer but wasn't sure since it talked about individual foods and I had combined different items with different shelf lives.  I know it ultimately depends on the item with the shortest life span.

Comment: no it doesn't depend on the item with the shortest life span. Bacteria generally live in all human foods, and you have to remove a bacteria living condition to make it durable. If you mix two foods, you might be adding back the missing condition. For example, gelatine is durable because it has no water, and water is durable because it has no calories. Mix gelatine and water and you get the medium labs use to grow bacterial colonies. And the other question doesn't talk about individual foods, it talks about categories of foods.